# Looking for preventive from "not responding" C#

Tags: c#, hex, filesystemwatcher

Yesterday my teachers gives me a task to make something like database in .txt file which has to contains hexes and a C# application which takes all hexes from this database, also with its offSets. Then i gotta use it,the offset, to take the hex from file on this offset and compare the both haxes, does they are same.
I am using `fileSystemWatcher` to "spy" chosen directory for new files and with one, two, three or little bit more files it works perfect but if i try to copy very "big" folder the application stops - "not responding".
I have try to find from where the problem comes like i adding and deleting functions and found the "black sheep" -the function which have to take the file's hex which is comply on the given offset.

```
  public string filesHex(string path,int bytesToRead,string offsetLong)
  {
      byte[] byVal;

      try
      {
          using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
          {
              BinaryReader brFile = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
              offsetLong = offsetLong.Replace("x", string.Empty);
              long result = 0;
              long.TryParse(offsetLong, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out result);
              fileStream.Position = result;
              byte[] offsetByte = brFile.ReadBytes(0);
              string offsetString = HexStr(offsetByte);
              //long offset = System.Convert.ToInt64(offsetString, 16);
              byVal = brFile.ReadBytes(bytesToRead);
          }
          string hex = HexStr(byVal).Substring(2);

          return hex;
      }
```

Comment: [Related, maybe dupe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025829/how-to-prevent-a-not-responding-message-on-a-windows-title-bar)

Comment: Did your teacher teach you about multithreading?

Comment: No but i have a little bit knowledge about it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could create a new Thread and run the `filesHex` method in it.

You can change your string inside the thread code and get it's value after like this:

```
 public string hex="";
 public void filesHex(string path,int bytesToRead,string offsetLong)
 {
        byte[] byVal;


      using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      {
          BinaryReader brFile = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
          offsetLong = offsetLong.Replace("x", string.Empty);
          long result = 0;
          long.TryParse(offsetLong, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out result);
          fileStream.Position = result;
          byte[] offsetByte = brFile.ReadBytes(0);
          string offsetString = HexStr(offsetByte);
          //long offset = System.Convert.ToInt64(offsetString, 16);
          byVal = brFile.ReadBytes(bytesToRead);
      }
      hex = HexStr(byVal).Substring(2);


  }
```

This would be your call:

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(() => filesHex("a",5,"A"));//example for parameters.
  thread.Start();
    string hexfinal=hex;//here you can acess the desired string.
```

Now it would not freeze the main UI thread because you run your method on a sperate thread.

Goodluck.

Comment: Further restructuring is probably required - `filesHex` takes parameters and returns a value which is thrown away with this code.

Comment: Ok, but to use it in thread it must not contains any arguments

Comment: @KenTavur oh. look my updated answer please. edited it.,

Comment: Let me try it and i am gonna give feedback

Comment: @KenTavur alright..come back with results .Goodluck.

Comment: As you may see it returns string. Would you give me an example how to use it in my code ? I mean how to use this thread in if statement like: if(hexReadFromDataBase == *here must be the string returned from the function*)

Comment: @Slashy, i am so sorry but i can't get it :/ 
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                    Thread thread = new Thread(() => filesHex("a",5,"A"));//example for parameters.
  thread.Start();
//What to type here in If statement to compare the hex from database and this took from file
         }

Comment: @KenTavur the `hexfinal` string handle you hex string. just use it.

Comment: With this answer you're attempting to set `hexfinal` as soon as you've started the thread.  This won't work - you need to wait for the thread to finish running.  There's a much larger task here than just putting the function in a thread, and not enough context to be able to advise how to do that.

Comment: @Slashy, it doesnt work. The application freezes again

Comment: @Alexmelyon  do you something else