# How to avoid "Not Responding" message in a form in a large Import from Excel to SQL SERVER

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, forms

My program import and export data from/to an Excel to/from my DataBase. You have to choose the excel file you want from and open file dialog and then click Send button.

Edit: The problem is that when i do import method, it makes my form shows "Not responding" message. The CargarNumero() method makes a select and update for every single INSERT (this table has 7K rows).

`Import`

```
private void importarDatos()
{
        DB con = new DB(path);

        string tabNombre = "";
        string tabApellidos = "";
        string tabID = "";
        SqlDecimal tabImporte = 0;
        int porc = 0;
        string year = "";

        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(txtFilePath.Text);
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Excel._Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

        xlRange = xlWorksheet.get_Range("A1", Missing.Value);
        xlRange = xlRange.get_End(Excel.XlDirection.xlToRight);
        xlRange = xlRange.get_End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown);

        string downAddress = xlRange.get_Address(
            false, false, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        xlRange = xlWorksheet.get_Range("A1", downAddress);

        object[,] values = (object[,])xlRange.Value2;

        int rowCount = values.GetLength(0);
        int colCount = values.GetLength(1);

        CargaProgreso cp = cargarProgreso();
        cp.Show();

        if ((cboYear.Visible) && (!cboYear.Text.Equals("")))
        {
            year = cboYear.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
        }

        for (int i = 2; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
            {
                if (j == 1)
                {
                    tabNombre = values[i, j].ToString();
                }
                else if (j == 2)
                {
                    tabApellidos = values[i, j].ToString();
                }
                else if (j == 3)
                {
                    tabID = values[i, j].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    tabImporte = Convert.ToDecimal(values[i, j].ToString());
                }
            }
            string query = "INSERT...";
            try
            {
                porc = Convert.ToInt32(i * 100 / rowCount);
                cp.Progreso.Value = porc;
                con.Consulta(query);
                Thread.Sleep(1);
                con.Cerrar();
                cargarNumero();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error en la importación " + ex);
            }
        }
        cp.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Importación de datos completada");
    }
```

`Export`

```
private void exportarDatos(Excel.Application xlApp, Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        string ruta = "*";
        sfd.InitialDirectory = ruta;
        sfd.DefaultExt = "xlsx";
        sfd.Filter = "Excel Files |*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xlsb";

        DB con = new DB(path);

        int porc = 0;

        CargaProgreso cp = cargarProgreso();
        cp.Text = "Exportando a Excel...";

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("*", con.Conexion);
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        DataColumnCollection dcCollection = dt.Columns;

        if (!Directory.Exists(ruta))
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(ruta);
        }
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("¿Desea guardar la Copia de seguridad?", "Copia de seguridad", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < (dt.Rows.Count + 1); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j < (dt.Columns.Count + 1); j++)
                    {
                        if (i == 1)
                        {
                            xlApp.Cells[i, j] = dcCollection[j - 1].ToString();
                        }
                        xlApp.Cells[i + 1, j] = dt.Rows[i - 1][j - 1].ToString();
                    }
                    porc = Convert.ToInt32(i * 100 / dt.Rows.Count);
                    cp.Progreso.Value = porc;  
                }
                cp.Close();
                xlWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(sfd.FileName);
                xlWorkbook.Saved = true;
                xlWorkbook.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Copia de Seguridad creada en " + sfd.FileName);
            }
        }
        con.Cerrar();
        cp.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Well, you can't see your changes because you call cExcel.Close when you exit from the first code.

Comment: My form(b) has just 2 labels and 2 textbos due to show progress of the data import. In both case the form is showed but where i have the problem it doesnt show the labels nor textboxes (actually it doesnt show even the format properties of the elements like background color etc).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have in one form the reference to the other. You can do this ny creating  form B inside of an EventHandler of A and Show it. The data you want to have visible in A (from B), you can populate into a list, or what ever and have it retrieved.

The other way is to use custom events that would signal between the forms that something needs to happen with the data that comes from the Eventarguments

Comment: The problem I have is that when i call cExcel.Show() in if (rbComplementaria.Checked) it doesnt show the labels and the texts of the other form but in if (rbSustitutiva.Checked) the first cExcel.Show is doing alright but not the second one (I mean when it has connection and commandtext it doesnt work properly but i dont know if its because of that).

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea where the issue is and I do not believe that you will find it any time soon. What I can see is aprox. 100 lines of code (or even more) in one method event handler. This is insane. You should refactor this code in a more meaningful manner and you will find the error much easier. You have several separate blocks of code. First of all you ahould have a Data access layer. Second, you can utilize several strategies for the checkBox scenarios. Please refactor it. I doubt you will find anyone that will be that willing to debug 100 lines of code.

Comment: Yes that is what Im going to do. Sorry Im a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this thread. If anyone else need help.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11027023/6223629